# how to implement multiple table priority wise searching in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, search

For Example : what is Backend Developer ?

1. Remove stop keyword "what is"
2. Show those profile which  contain "backend developer"
3. Then show those profile which contain "backend"
4. Then show those profile which contain "developer"
5. Then show those profile which contain synonyms and subcategory of "backend" and "developer".

we have to two types of table to show data
1.user profile ( searching on the basis of skills , interest and education)
2.feeds (searching on the basis of title , description)
and we need results from these two tables

Comment: Please provide your effort with some code so others can support you building it properly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use table with scope then add checks the search keyword is similar to any scope and show them